# Compiler error while trying to read evtx file?

Tags: c++

I am getting the compiler error _T identifier not found..kindly help me in resolving this  error?? Also i want to make this program in C??
But first resolving errors so that i can debug and watch the flow?? Compiling it on VS 2008

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long ULONG;

typedef struct _EVENTLOGHEADER {
ULONG HeaderSize;
ULONG Signature;
ULONG MajorVersion;
ULONG MinorVersion;
ULONG StartOffset;
ULONG EndOffset;
ULONG CurrentRecordNumber;
ULONG OldestRecordNumber;
ULONG MaxSize;
ULONG Flags;
ULONG Retention;
ULONG EndHeaderSize;
} EVENTLOGHEADER, *PEVENTLOGHEADER;  

typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef struct _EVENTLOGRECORD {
    DWORD Length;
    DWORD Reserved;
    DWORD RecordNumber;
    DWORD TimeGenerated;
    DWORD TimeWritten;
    DWORD EventID;
    WORD  EventType;
    WORD  NumStrings;
    WORD  EventCategory;
    WORD  ReservedFlags;
    DWORD ClosingRecordNumber;
    DWORD StringOffset;
    DWORD UserSidLength;
    DWORD UserSidOffset;
    DWORD DataLength;
    DWORD DataOffset;
} EVENTLOGRECORD, *PEVENTLOGRECORD;

void main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\\Application.evtx",ios::in|ios::binary);

    if(file.is_open()){
        _EVENTLOGHEADER logheader;
        _EVENTLOGRECORD logRecord;

        //Reading the header
        file.read((char*)&logheader,sizeof(_EVENTLOGHEADER));

        int startOfLog;
        //Loop on every record
        for(unsigned int numberFile=0;numberFile < logheader.CurrentRecordNumber -1;numberFile++){
            //Save the position
            startOfLog = file.tellg();
            //Read log record
            file.read((char*)&logRecord,sizeof(_EVENTLOGRECORD));

            /*******************************************************
            Here are the other information (section 'Remarks' on the 'EVENTLOGRECORD structure' link 
            ********************************************************/

            //Reading sourcename
            wchar_t buffData;
            wstring SourceName;
            file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
            while(buffData!=_T('\0')){
                SourceName.push_back(buffData);
                file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
            }

            //Reading computer name
            wstring ComputerName;
            file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
            while(buffData!=_T('\0')){
                ComputerName.push_back(buffData);
                file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
            }

            //Sets the position to the SID offset 
            int readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.UserSidOffset;
            file.seekg(readCursor);

            char * userSid = NULL;
            if(logRecord.UserSidLength != 0)
            {
                userSid = (PCHAR)malloc(logRecord.UserSidLength);
                file.read(userSid,logRecord.UserSidLength); //Reading the sid
                //Here you can work on the SiD (but you need win32 API).If you need it, I could show you how i deal with this sid 
                free(userSid);
            }

            //Sets the position to the Strings offset
            readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.StringOffset;
            file.seekg(readCursor);
            wstring buffString;
            vector<wstring> allStrings;
            //Reading all the strings
            for(int i=0; i< logRecord.NumStrings; i++) {
                file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
                while(buffData!=_T('\0')){
                    buffString.push_back(buffData);
                    file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
                }
                allStrings.push_back(buffString);
                buffString.clear();
            }

            //Sets the position to the Data offset
            readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.DataOffset;
            file.seekg(readCursor);
            unsigned char *Data = (unsigned char *)malloc(logRecord.DataLength*sizeof(unsigned char));
            file.read((char*)Data,logRecord.DataLength); //Lecture des données

            //Sets the position to the end of log offset
            readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.Length - sizeof(DWORD) ;
            file.seekg(readCursor);
            DWORD length;
            file.read((char*)&length,sizeof(DWORD));

            //Do what you want with the log record

            //Clean before reading next log
            ComputerName.clear();
            SourceName.clear();
            allStrings.clear();
            free(Data);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not possible in C without completely rewriting it.

Comment: You should specify, which compiler and environment you're using.

Comment: How to write it in C @g-makulik..Actually want to read evtx file using c only

Comment: I depends on a lot of things how to do this. Which API should be used etc. I also don't see any good reason for rewriting that code in C.

Answer (score 4):

`_T` is a Windows-specific means of specifying *either* a narrow character constant/string literal, *or* a wide character constant/string literal, depending on the project settings. It requires appropriate `#include` directives that are not present in your code, it's not a compiler-defined macro.

However, you don't need it. You're using it in `while(buffData!=_T('\0'))`, but `buffData` has type `wchar_t`, independent of project settings. In that case, just use a wide character constant: `L'\0'`.

Comment: well thanks for telling but this code is ahuge mess up after ommitting the mistake..i included header file windows.h also but its giving more errors

Answer (score 1):

The `_T` macro is defined in `Tchar.h` so it would seem that you merely need to include that header.

That said, you don't appear to be writing code that can be compiler for both ANSI and Unicode so it would make more sense to stop using `TCHAR` and prefix your wide characters with `L`. So, instead of writing `_T('\0')` write `L'\0'`, or even just plain old `0`.

Comment: write only...i did it but still not compiling

Comment: Do you want me to debug your entire program? I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: True..thanks..i compiled it actually vector header file was missing...Davisd i want to convert in c ...Can i hav pseudo code/steps to do that

Comment: No, that's asking too much.

Comment: well.. i am trying to read an evtx file...i have to create a generic program In C..cross platform...if you find any useful link provide me with that i'll be glad..or help??

Comment: The code is easy enough to port to C. Try it.